# Oracle SQL Query to calculate the average of a data set, excluding outliers

Tags: sql, oracle, average, sql-navigator

I have a query which contains the correct conditions and fields that i want to display:

```
  SELECT t.business_process_id,
         COUNT (tsp.status) AS COUNT,
         ROUND (AVG (tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS average,
         ROUND (MAX (tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MAX,
         ROUND (MIN (tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MIN,
         ROUND (MEDIAN (tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MEDIAN,
         ROUND (STDDEV (tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date), 2) AS std_deviation
    FROM transaction_status_period tsp, transaction t
   WHERE     t.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
         AND tsp.status = 'R'
         AND tsp.end_date IS NOT NULL
         AND tsp.userid NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A')
         AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM tsp.start_date) =
                 EXTRACT (DAY FROM tsp.end_date)
         AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.start_date) =
                 EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.end_date)
         AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM tsp.start_date) =
                 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM tsp.end_date)
         AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.start_date) = 2013
         AND NOT EXISTS
                     (SELECT 1
                        FROM transaction_status_period tsp1
                       WHERE     tsp1.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
                             AND tsp.userid = tsp1.userid
                             AND tsp1.status = 'S'
                             AND tsp1.timestamp < tsp.timestamp)
GROUP BY t.business_process_id
```

The average calculated by the query is of the whole data set in question (for the year = 2013). Is there a way to get the query to calculate the average of all data from 2013 excluding outliers? I.e. find the average of the date difference of `(tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date)` where, the majority of observations fall, for the year 2013?

Would the `percentile_cont` function work? I am not familiar with it but i do know it calculates the percentile of a particular column. In my case, I'm looking for the average date difference between `(tsp.end_date - tsp.start_date)`, but the average of majority of the data points (excluding outliers).

Any help would be much appreciated. Perhaps I am tackling this query in the wrong way.

Comment: Can you provide a definition of outliers?  For statistical purposes, the median is often used as a more stable "center" of data.  You already have that in your query.

Comment: By outliers i mean the 20%-30% of averages that are no where near the 70%-80% of averages.

Comment: @JT2013 - Normally, "outliers" would be defined as something like "data points more than n standard deviations from the mean" where n is some value chosen based on the business requirements.  If data is normally distributed, +/- 1 standard deviations would include roughly 67% of the data, 2 would include roughly 95% of the data, 3 would include roughly 99% of the data.  Do you want to exclude the top and bottom 10% of data points rather than basing the determination on some statistical test?  Or do you have a statistical test in mind that discards 20-30% of your data?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry I am not explaining this correctly. But yes, i would like to exclude the top and bottom 10% of data points. That's exactly what I would be looking for. Perhaps even have the option to exclude the top and bottom 15% of data points.

Comment: @JustinCave any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this solve your problem?

Calculate your average and standard deviation in an inline view and then use that
to define your outliers. Assuming you consider an outlier twice the standard of the mean then:

```
SELECT calc.business_process_id,
 COUNT (calc.status) AS COUNT,
 ROUND (AVG (calc.end_date - calc.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS average,
 ROUND (MAX (calc.end_date - calc.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MAX,
 ROUND (MIN (calc.end_date - calc.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MIN,
 ROUND (MEDIAN (calc.end_date - calc.start_date), 2) * 24 * 60 AS MEDIAN,
 ROUND (STDDEV (calc.end_date - calc.start_date), 2) AS std_deviation
FROM (SELECT t.business_process_id,
         tsp.status,
         tsp.start_date,
         tsp.end_date, 
         ntile(100) over (order by (tsp.end_date-tsp.start_date)) as percentiles
      FROM transaction_status_period tsp, transaction t 
      WHERE     t.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
      AND tsp.status = 'R'
      AND tsp.end_date IS NOT NULL
      AND tsp.userid NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A')
      AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM tsp.start_date) =
          EXTRACT (DAY FROM tsp.end_date)
      AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.start_date) =
          EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.end_date)
      AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM tsp.start_date) =
          EXTRACT (MONTH FROM tsp.end_date)
      AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM tsp.start_date) = 2013
      AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
                FROM transaction_status_period tsp1
               WHERE     tsp1.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
                     AND tsp.userid = tsp1.userid
                     AND tsp1.status = 'S'
                     AND tsp1.timestamp < tsp.timestamp)
  ) calc
WHERE calc.percentiles >=10 
AND calc.percentiles <=90
GROUP BY calc.business_process_id
```

Comment: as i mentioned above, i would like to exclude the top and bottom 10% of data points. That's exactly what I would be looking for. Perhaps even have the option to exclude the top and bottom 15% of data points.

Comment: Think you can take advantage of the ntile function which "divides an ordered data set into a number of buckets".So ntile(100) will divide you query into 100 buckets and then you can just exclude the top and bottom percentiles. I have updated the code to show how this could be done.